# Ввод с консоли на kotlin

Tags: ооп, kotlin

Нигде не могу найти дельную информацию как считать с консоли тот или иной символ ( букву) и записать ее например в кнопку на панели

Answer (score 1):

Kotlin по сути тут ни при чем. При чем среда исполнения.
Если это JVM, то так же как и в Java.
Консоль читать из `System.in`, писать в `System.out`.
https://metanit.com/java/tutorial/2.9.php

Работа с кнопкой тоже зависит от UI framework, который используете.